# Windows Home Server 2011

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-home-server

Does Windows Home Server 2011 allow multiple  logins to the same account at the same time? Or just one at a time. I've tried to log onto my Home Server, and when my sister logs on I get booted off.
And if so how would I Program/setup the server for multi users so we don't get booted off? If you reply back give good examples of how to setup as I'm having problems setting up my server.

I have another question as well, can you link a windows XP professional service pack 3 that meets all requirements to access the same server? If someone knows how to set this up to the server please give full example of how to as I'm having a hard time doing so.

Thank you.....

Comment: Why is this tagged with Linux, ubuntu, usb and router?

Comment: tags are corrected by the way

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simply you can't.

I guess you need to access family folders and files together at the same time. if you're really looking for that, i would suggest you below readings

Windows Home Server 2011 doesn't support roaming profiles, which is what you're really looking for. That requires Active Directory.

If you want, you can move users' Documents folder to shares on the server, which will accomplish much of what you probably really want, but settings, installed applications, etc. will have to be set up individually on each computer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 3 connections, 2 RPD and 1 local.

> There is no limit for share access - 10 users (+1 Guest) can connect at the same time.
>
> The 3 concurrent limit is for RDP + local sessions to the server.

[Source](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85044f48-b35a-4327-9471-490cb42883bf/how-many-concurrent-connections-does-whs-support?forum=whssoftware)

Further reading (outside the scope of the question) about setting up [concurrent RDP in WHS 2011](http://www.theofficemaven.com/faq/whsol-2011/multiple-simultaneous-connections)